# Testing in jasmine- returns error of TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am new to writing test units and am receiving the following error when trying to execute my test:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object  (evaluating '$scope.createRoleForm.canCreateAccount=false')
```

The function I want test is:

```
function enableAccountRoles() {
    $scope.createRoleForm.canCreateAccount = false;
    $scope.createRoleForm.canListAccounts = false;
    $scope.createRoleForm.canSearchAllChat = false;
    $scope.createRoleForm.canManageSite = false;
  }
```

and my test code is

```
 it('should call enableAccountRoles', function() {
    this.scope.enableAccountRoles();
  })
```

I know that this isn't complete as I have no expectation- do I need to set the value of the variables in the test file before running the test unit?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to set the expected value. See the example below.

Javascript function to test

```
function Add(x, y) {
return x + y;
}
```

TestCase code:

```
describe("Math Test Cases", function () {

it("Additon Test Case", function () {
    expect(Add(3, 4)).toBe(7);
});
});
```

Angular Test code:

```
var MyApp = angular.module("MyModule", []);
MyApp.controller("MyController", function ($scope) {

$scope.number1 = 0;
$scope.number2 = 0;
$scope.total = 0;

$scope.Addition = function () {
    $scope.total = $scope.number1 + $scope.number2;
};
});
```

Angular TestCase:

```
describe("Angular Test cases", function () {

it("Addition test case", function () {
    module("MyModule");

    var scope = {};

    inject(function ($controller) {
        $controller("MyController", { $scope: scope });
    });

    scope.number1 = 4;
    scope.number2 = 5;
    scope.Addition();
    expect(scope.total).toBe(9);
});
});
```